# Responsive Html - vertical line across image

Tags: jquery, css, html

Please help me create a html section like below image. i have used div table and created basic structure. But i cannot able implement the vertical line across the centr image.As this is responsive page i cannot able to give fixed values.Please guide me on this [image]

Comment: Why not use a right border?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How can i place image over right border

Comment: `i have used div table and created basic structure` please post your first draft, We need something to improve on,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the icon is an image, you should know sizes in px, right?
Then, wrap everything inside a parent element, the icon and the table itself, like the example shown here.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.parent table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #e5e5e5
 url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nature-and-ecology/128/Nature__Eco_water_reuse-64.png) no-repeat;
  border-radius: 32px;
}
.left,
.right {
  border: 1px solid #252122;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
table span {
  display: block;
}
table td span:first-child {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Transparent icon by iconfinder.com, example only -->
<div class="parent">
  <!--Positioned absolute, image transparent, css background set manually-->
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <table>
    <td class="left">
      <span>FROM</span>
      <span>Select Departure</span>
    </td>
    <td class="right">
      <span>TO</span>
      <span>Select Arrival</span>
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
```